# How write parameterised command in ADODC command text

Tags: vb6

I have one table: there is the id field, and I want to compare it with textbox.text
when i write command as like,

```
select * from Table1 where id = text1.text
```

that time this popup message will display

> no value given for one or more required parameter

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `ADODB.Parameter` class along with the `ADO.Command`. Here's [an example](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=3687)